# MPI_Testany отрицательный индекс

Tags: c, распараллеливание, mpi

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Вызываю в цикле несколько `Irecv()`, после чего вызываю `MPI_Testany` и в индексе получаю число -32766, поток сразу же завершает работу.